# How to differentiate enemies from allies in Battlefield 1 for a color-blind?

Tags: battlefield-1

I'm new to Battlefield and I need to know if there is an easy way to difference between allies and enemies. I mean, in Star Wars Battlefront is easy for me to difference between rebels and empire uniforms, but is a little bit more difficult to me in Battlefield 1 because I'm not familiar with WW uniforms. I have to add that I'm daltonic so it's not easy to me relate them to colors. Is there another way? probably a mark or text or symbol near the soldier? Because right know I can only realize that is an enemy if he starts shooting me.

Comment: There should be an option for colorblind people olin which makes UI color-blind friendly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to recognize enemies in this game is to look at what they have on their head + details of the uniforms.

Here is an image of every class for every faction.
[image]

Next, it's important to know which faction you are and which one you are playing against.

**Ottoman Empire vs British Empire**

- Fao Fortress
- Sinai Desert
- Suez

**Austro-Hungarian Empire vs Kingdom of Italy**

- Empire's Edge
- Monte Grappa

**British/US vs German Empire**

- Amiens
- St Quentin Scar
- Argonne Forest
- Ballroom Blitz

This handy youtube video also shows you this information, but it uses the color to distinguish the enemies from the friendlies.

[Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mBHIHt3YyLs)

Answer (score 4):

There is a way to make enemies distinct from allies: Spotting.

[Here is a video from battlefield.com outlining the feature in BF1.](https://www.battlefield.com/games/battlefield-1/tips/videos/how-to-spot-enemies-battlefield-1)

This will put a diamond-shaped, red mark over the head of an enemy soldier for you and all of your allies on the map. The mark does not last particularly long, but the color is affected by the colorbind options for the UI, if that is useful to you.

Allies have blue, green, or yellow icons over their heads that are circles. Allies appear on the minimap as blue dots, enemies that have been spotted or are firing weapons appear as red dots.

As far as visually distinct, there are several different factions in BF1 - it's not as simple as Rebellion vs. Empire - and frankly as someone who is *not* colorblind I have trouble telling them apart. Many of the uniforms are simply drab grey or brown.

Good ways to identify an enemy solider are:

- Look for a mark indicating spotted enemies.
- Look on your minimap for any enemy activity (taking objectives)
- Look for players near objectives that do not belong to you, or players heading towards objectives that do belong to you
- Look for soldiers shooting at your allies or you (not terribly useful in the moment, I know)

A lot of this can also be chalked up to "game sense", as you play the game more you'll naturally develop a better feel for where the enemies will be coming from to take objectives, and when there is an enemy presence at key points on the map.

Comment: Do enemies appear on the radar when they fire their guns now?  I know that at release they did NOT, and I remember that because it was different than previous Battlefield games.  I haven't played in a few months, so this may have been changed in a recent patch.

Comment: I assumed they did - I haven't played in quite a while. I'll remove that for now to be safe.

Comment: Only the direction the shot came from is shown on the compass-map. Scout spot flare is the best thing to light up the map

Comment: @Rapitor Ah, I see - not very useful in that case! Scout's flare is covered in the video.

Comment: Spotting is something that one should definitely do, but I'm not sure how that would help colorblind player, given that circles over friendlies' and enemies' heads are exactly the same shape and size, only difference is the color.

Comment: @vartec The spotting colors are affected by the UI colorblind settings. The options may not work for everyone, but they're there.

Comment: Colors, but not the shapes. DICE really screwed up with that one, should have been diamond for enemy, circle for friendly or something like that.

Comment: Based on my memory and the video in my answer, enemies' icons are diamonds and allies are circles. Did a recent patch change this?